Could we get the expected output with cross join similar to the SQL code
I am trying to write a similar code with cross join in R like that we do in proc SQL.
However, I am unable to write a code, please help me.
Here is the data:
data.frame(
  all_names = c("PARENT1", "CHILD1", "CHILD2", "CHILD3", "PARENT2", "PARENT3", "CHILD4", "CHILD5", "CHILD6", "PARENT7", "CHILD7", "CHILD8")
)

   all_names
1    PARENT1
2     CHILD1
3     CHILD2
4     CHILD3
5    PARENT2
6    PARENT3
7     CHILD4
8     CHILD5
9     CHILD6
10   PARENT7
11    CHILD7
12    CHILD8

Expected output:
data.frame(
  parent= c("PARENT1", "PARENT1", "PARENT1", "PARENT1", "PARENT2", "PARENT2", "PARENT2", "PARENT3", "PARENT3", "PARENT3", "PARENT4", "PARENT4", "PARENT4"),
child=c("CHILD1", "CHILD2", "CHILD3", "CHILD4", "PARENT5", "PARENT6", "CHILD4", "CHILD5", "CHILD6",  "CHILD7", "CHILD8")
)

    parent  child
1  PARENT1 CHILD1
2  PARENT1 CHILD2
3  PARENT1 CHILD3
4  PARENT2 CHILD4
5  PARENT2 CHILD5
6  PARENT2 CHILD6
7  PARENT3 CHILD4
8  PARENT3 CHILD5
9  PARENT3 CHILD6
10 PARENT4 CHILD7
11 PARENT4 CHILD8

I tried something as below but could not proceed further and got struck, i was trying to do the cross join
data %>% mutate(seq=row_number())

child <- data %>% filter(stringr::str_detect(all_names,'CHILD'))
parent <- data %>% filter(stringr::str_detect(all_names,'PARENT'))

parent %>% cross_join(child) %>% filter(seq.x <= seq.y)


In the example there is a PARENT4 in the output but no PARENT4 in the input so we are assuming that PARENT4 in the output was supposed to be PARENT7.
The key here is to use consecutive_id to form parent and child runs. The parent runs will be odd and the child even.  If we subtract one from a child run we get the corresponding parent run.
library(dplyr)

tmp <- dat %>%
   mutate(runs = consecutive_id(grepl("PARENT", all_names)),
          p = runs %% 2)

p <- tmp %>% filter(p == 1)
ch <- tmp %>% filter(p == 0) %>% mutate(runs = runs - 1)
p %>%
  inner_join(ch, "runs", relationship = "many-to-many") %>%
  select(parent = all_names.x,  child = all_names.y)

giving
    parent  child
1  PARENT1 CHILD1
2  PARENT1 CHILD2
3  PARENT1 CHILD3
4  PARENT2 CHILD4
5  PARENT2 CHILD5
6  PARENT2 CHILD6
7  PARENT3 CHILD4
8  PARENT3 CHILD5
9  PARENT3 CHILD6
10 PARENT7 CHILD7
11 PARENT7 CHILD8

Alternately after creating tmp we could use SQL
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select p.all_names as parent, ch.all_names as child
  from tmp p
  inner join tmp ch on p.p = 1 and ch.p = 0 and p.runs = ch.runs - 1")

